# Jquery won't remove or add class to all 'ids'

Tags: jquery, class

so this is my code:

```
$(window).resize(function()
{
   var ancho = $(window).width();
   if(ancho <= 739){
       $('#text').removeClass('col-xs-6').addClass('col-xs-12');
   }
   else{
       $('#text').removeClass('col-xs-12').addClass('col-xs-6');
   }
})
.resize();
```

I decided to copy paste the html with the #text id to now have 2 copies of it, however this jquery above will only affect the first copy, what should I do to affect both copies? Thanks :D

Comment: Don't use duplicate IDs...

Comment: You can try `$('[id="text"]')` might work but not recommended. Use common class and use class selector

Comment: Sure but is there a way not to have to repeat the whole code?

Comment: Jan is correct, you should make the html have class `text`, not an ID of `text`.  IDs should be unique.

Comment: When objects have something in common, they should belong to a common `class`.  When you want to `id`entify a unique object, use an `id`. To use an `id` to identify a group is not correct.

Comment: thanks guys, didnt know I shouldn't repeat ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID's are unique. When you call an ID like that : `$('#text')` it does `document.getElementById(text)` and return **only 1 result**.

If you do want an invalide HTML, you can always use `$('div#text')` or whatever tag it is, but why would you do that? When there is multiple times the same ID, you should change it for a class.